# How to use mysql select rows from multiple categories and display a list with data for each category?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say i have a database design like this:

for the data:

```
id |    title     | category
1  | first title  | 1
2  | second title | 4
3  | third title  | 5
4  | fourth title | 2
5  | fifth title  | 3
6  | other title  | 1
```

and for the categories:

```
id | name 
1  | music 
2  | movies
3  | funny 
4  | people 
5  | sport
```

How can i output a list with each category with item title from that category?

somethink like:

```
<div>
<h1>music</h1>
<div>first title</div>
<div>other title</div>
<div>

<div>
<h1>movies</h1>
<div>fourth title</div>
<div>

// and so on...
```

I don't know how to formulate the mysql query for a result like this...

Can somebody please advise me? (i hope the example can be understood easily)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
i used Eugen Rieck's code but i don't know how to do the following thing**

how can i order by the `categories.id` and `titles.id` in the same time eventually use a where condition after that?

something like this:  `ORDER BY titles.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10 WHERE titles.views > 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first table is called `titles` and your second table `categories`, use a query like

```
SELECT categories.name as cat, tiltes.title as title
FROM categories INNER JOIN titles ON titles.category=categories.id
ORDER BY categories.id
```

and then do a group change loop

```
define('MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT',10);

$cat='';
$tcount=0;
while (true) {
  //Fetch a row depending on your DB framework, eg. mysql_fetch_row()
  if ($row['cat']!=$cat) {
    if ($cat!='') echo '</div>';
    $cat=$row['cat'];
    $tcount=MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT;
    echo "<div><h1>$cat</h1>";
  }
  if ($tcount--<=0) continue;
  echo '<div>'.$row['title'].'</div>';
}
if ($cat!='') echo '</div>';
```

**EDIT**

I updated the above code to limit the count of titles displayed per category to `MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT` - please understand, that this is very inefficient, if the average number of titles per category is much higher than `MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT`.

Comment: thank you very much! this code of yours saved me from multiple queries and now i can also add a pagination. thanks again!

Comment: however, i have a question... how can i order the `categories.id` and `titles.id` eventually use a where condition after that? can you help me?

Comment: Just put it in the query: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <whatever> ORDER BY categories.id, titles.id` - it is important though, that your sorting keeps hte categories together.

Comment: `SELECT 
  
  categories.cat_name as cat,
  videos.id as video_id,
  videos.title as video_title,
  videos.views as video_views
  
FROM categories 

INNER JOIN videos ON videos.category = categories.cat_id
 
ORDER BY categories.cat_id, videos.id LIMIT 10` using this only shows 10 items from the first category.

Comment: It show 10 rows - that means it shows 10 titles, no matter what category they belong to.

Comment: yes, but how the query should look do display 10 titles from each category?

Comment: yes, that worked. thank you, but wouldn't be more efficient to limit directly the query?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is an efficiency penalty with big categories - there is no (straightforward) way of limiting the titles per category: We folded the parent/child query into one, which makes the concept of a row cover both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t.title,
    c.name
FROM
    titles t
INNER JOIN categories c
    ON c.id = t.category
ORDER BY
    c.name
ASC
```

This gives you a list of all titles ordered by category. What you do in PHP is roughly the following:

```
$prevCategory = null;

while(fetchRows)
{
    $newCategory = $row['name'];

    if($prevCategory != $newCategory)
    {
        echo '<ul>{category name}</ul>';
    }

    echo '<li>{title}</li>';

    $prevCategory = {category name};

}
```

Note that this is semi-pseudo code. It doesn't close the previous UL and isn't according to the HTML format you seek. This should get you going though.